# pass vector by reference or by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I have the following function:

```
void write_to_File(std::vector<uint16_t> *vector) {
    std::fstream file;
    file.open(writePath, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
    if (file.is_open()) {
         file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(*vector)[0]), vector->size()*sizeof(uint16_t));
    } else {
        std::cout << "file not found!";
        return;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

This method doesn't actually change `vector`, but since it is getting casted I can't make it a const reference. If I use just a reference then cpplint will complain it has to be either const or a pointer.

> warning: Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer: std::vector &vector  [runtime/references] [2]

Should I just ignore cpplint and make it a reference, keep this code (with the pointer) or make it a const reference and cast a copy?

Comment: Pass by const reference. You can cast to `const char*`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm gonna bang my head against a wall for not thinking of this, thank you.

Comment: You are not using anything inherent in pointers, pass by reference.

Comment: [OT]: Care to endianness issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the correct answer in your case is:

```
void write_to_File(const std::vector<uint16_t>& vector) {
    std::fstream file;
    file.open(writePath, std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
    if (file.is_open()) {
         const auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&vector[0]);
         file.write(ptr, vector.size()*sizeof(uint16_t));
    } else {
        std::cout << "file not found!";
        return;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

However, I think the cpplint error is wrong (this is a matter of opinion of course).  I use the rule "if `nullptr` is a valid value, use a pointer, otherwise use a reference".

Comment: is the `const auto ptr` necessary? Also your code contains a syntax error, `(*vector)` should be just `vector` since it's no longer a pointer, same with the `->`

Comment: @Arrow - no the `const auto ptr` is not necessary - it's just that without it, I get horizontal scroll bars, and I **hate** horizontal scroll bars.  I also happen to think that the code is a bit easier to read because it separates out "calculating where the data is", and "writing the data to disk" (but YMMV).  (Fixing the syntax errors of course *is* necessary! - and done.)